# Python Pandas find which projects have intercepting dates

Tags: python, pandas

So I find with my datasets I have a few projects that take part during similar time periods. Sample data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Proj": ["a", "b", "c"],
               "Start": ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-15'],
               "End": ['2017-02-28','2017-03-01','2017-04-15'],
               "Mon": [0.8,0.4,0.5],
               "Tues": [0.6,0.4,0.5],
               "Wed": [0.4,0.1,0.5],
               "Thurs": [0.2,0,0.5],
               "Fri": [0,0.5,0.5]
               })
```

For example with the above dataset

Project A runs from '2017-01-01' to '2017-02-28'
however Project B runs from '2017-02-01' to '2017-03-01'
that means during '2017-02-01' to '2017-02-28' both project A and B are running at the same time.

What I'm looking to do is either make a new table showing the intersections or some way to visualize the data. If I need to transform it into a new table what I'm trying to do is make it look like

```
Start        End          Proj   Mon   Tues   Wed   Thurs   Fri
2017-01-01   2017-02-01   A      0.8    0.6   0.4   0.2     0
2017-02-01   2017-02-28   A,B    1.2    1     0.5   0.2     0.5
2017-02-28   2017-03-01   B      0.4    0.4   0.1   0       0.5
2017-03-15   2017-04-15   C      0.5    0.5   0.5   0.5     0.5
```

Any ideas how to transform the initial table to get that kind of output or what kind of visualization I can do to show something similar?

Comment: You absolutely want a timeseries here with each column representing each project's values, and if you'd like, you can add a "Weekday" column with the name of the weekday in each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would transform it like this:

```
date       A     B     C
2017-01-31 True  False False
2017-02-01 True  True  False
2017-02-02 True  True  False
```

So first you generate a DatetimeIndex from the first Start to the last End:

```
days = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=df.Start.min(), end=df.End.max(), freq='B')
```

Then you create a new DataFrame with that index and `columns=df.Proj`, with the initial value `False`:

```
gantt = pd.DataFrame(False, days, df.Proj)
```

Then change the cells to True where each project is active:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    gantt[row.Proj][row.Start:row.End] = True
```

Once you have the transformed table it should be easy to convert it into a table with the `True` cells colored differently, like a Gantt chart.

Comment: Not good as a data structure itself, by to improve visual readability I would omit the 'False's and only have the 'True's (or a symbol such as a x), so that overlaps can more easily be seen.

Comment: I managed to make the DateTimeIndex, but failing to get df2[proj][df.Start[proj]:df.End[proj]] = True to work

firstday = pd.to_datetime(df["Start"]).min()

dur = pd.to_datetime(df["End"]).max() - pd.to_datetime(df["Start"]).min()

rng = pd.date_range(firstday, periods=dur.days, freq='D')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.Proj, index=rng)